# unable to mount NTFS as readonly

Tags: puppy-linux, ntfs-3g

I'm using a PuppyLinux build with the Ubuntu Precise kernel.
NTFS partitions are always mounted as "rw" but i'd like to avoid this if it is not really necessary to prevent filesystem corruption.

When mounting manually i get this output:

```
# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1 -o remount,ro
dolphin: Unknown option 'R'.
dolphin: Use --help to get a list of available command line options.
# mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb1 on /initrd/mnt/dev_save type vfat     (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,quiet,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop1 on /initrd/pup_ro1 type ext2     (rw,noatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl)
tmpfs on /initrd/pup_rw type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1553964k)
tmpfs on /initrd/mnt/tmpfs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=165352k)
/dev/loop0 on /initrd/pup_ro2 type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop4 on /initrd/pup_ro4 type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop5 on /initrd/pup_ro5 type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop6 on /initrd/pup_ro6 type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop7 on /initrd/pup_ro7 type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop8 on /initrd/pup_ro8 type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop9 on /initrd/pup_ro9 type squashfs (ro,noatime)
unionfs on / type aufs (rw,relatime,si=3ac8a13a)
none on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=2,mode=620)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
shmfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=688636k)
/dev/loop2 on /initrd/pup_ro10 type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/sda1 type fuseblk     (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

How can i mount NTFS partitions as readonly?

Comment: You only need `remount` if the partition is already mounted.  If it's not, then `-o ro` should work.

Comment: yep, i knew that, i tried with and without it...

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run the command without `remount`?

Comment: yes, same output.

Comment: That's very odd.  What versions of `mount` and `mount.ntfs` are you running?  Also (and I don't know Puppy) what happens if you reboot into the default kernel?

Comment: You seem to have separated the options with the mount device and mount point. What happens if you run `mount -t ntfs-3g -o remount,ro /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1` ?

Comment: @garethTheRed: the default kernel is the one i'm running :)

Comment: @ Warwick: same output :(

Comment: I've just installed Puppy in a VM. It turns out that the `mount` command on Puppy is a script at `/bin/mount` and not the 'real' `mount` command.  To mount read only, use `ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1 -o ro` instead.